# Postgres doesn't let me use '$' in column alias

Tags: sql, postgresql, identifier

Postgres 14.
Are there any forbidden characters in aliasing columns?
I want to see '$' in column's name and it doesn't work. How can I get it done? Is there any magic function that could do that for me?

```
SELECT 
    id,
    currency as '$',
    available
from f_total
ORDER BY 
    id DESC
;
```

gives:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'$'"
LINE 3:  currency as '$',
                     ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 27
```

Same story when I use '€', '!', '<'. I expected it to be not executed against all syntax-verificators - it's just an insignificant string to be used on output ...
How to make my column to be named with such name?

Comment: Identifiers like column aliases are delimited with double quotes (`"`) not apostrophes (`'`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double-quotes (`"`) for identifiers:

```
currency AS "$"
```

See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)

Every string is allowed once double-quoted (with contained double-quotes doubled up). Doesn't mean it's a good idea to use "$" as identifier. It isn't.